# Offer code as downloadable file

Tags: feature-request, code-block, downloads

Maybe I am not the first one who got this idea.

There are many programming questions asked and answered on these sites. My idea is when the question or answer consists of a lot of code and the user wants it, he must copy-paste it. So how about providing a download button which will download the code as a file?

Comment: You could install [Select Code Block Buttons Script](http://stackapps.com/q/2553)

Comment: If you download the file then you need to open it again... I don't see how it's a significant improvement on copy and paste... "a lot" of code really isn't that much, there's only 30KB in total allowed so it's always a small size (that much code is a bad question though).

Comment: Martijn's suggestion to just implement this using a user script would be your best bet here - but really, _look out_ for questions that contain that much code. It's _very_ rare that so much code would be warranted, and you might get sucked into walking someone through the _entire_ debugging process, which can be as exhausting as it is exhaustive. Some folks can just suck the blood right out of you when it comes to that.

Comment: Large blocks of code are generally not encouraged on SO - neither in questions, nor in answers.

Answer (score 10):

We don't want to encourage users to be posting very large blocks of code, to the point that they would need to leverage a feature like this.  If you are coming across questions with this much code then the solution is to remove the unnecessary code, or encourage the author to do so.

If answers are containing that much code then it's a sign that the questions are too broad, and should be narrowed in scope.